# Using an image as a moving object in an animation

Tags: graphics, image, animation

I have following animation:

```
Animate[
 Graphics[{Translate[Rotate[Rectangle[], ψ Degree], {x, 0}], 
   Translate[Rotate[Rectangle[], -ψ Degree], {1.75 - x, 0}]}],
 {x, 0, 1},
 {ψ, 0, 90},
 AnimationRunning -> False
 ]
```

[image]

For rectangles it works perfectly, but when I try to put any image instead of these rectangles, it shows me "Image is not a Graphics primitive or directive" error. How to put any image (raster-, vector- based) and transform it the way like it does with primitives?

Comment: You can use `Inset` or `Texture`.

Comment: There are special commands for dealing with image objects such as `ImageRotate`.

Comment: Okay, but I also need to transform my image in the way it is done with primitives :)

Answer (score 3):

```
t = Texture@ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
p = {t, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
                VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}]}; 
Animate[ Graphics[{Translate[Rotate[p, ψ Degree], {x, 0}], 
                   Translate[Rotate[p, -ψ Degree], {1.75 - x, 0}]}], 
       {x, 0, 1}, {ψ, 0, 90}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: No images? Me too lazy to evaluate!

Comment: @YvesKlett uploading ...

Comment: You be using an acoustic coupler modem?

Comment: @YvesKlett Just a standard third world inet uplink